# Attach sources to binary library in Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, pdb-files

[In Eclipse, it's possible](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-source-attachment.htm) to "match" a `zip` archive (or a folder) containing sources to a compiled `jar`. This allows the debugger to do source-stepping on the associated sources with relatively low ceremony.

I'd like to do something similar in Visual Studio, given a `dll`, its associated `pdb` and the source code in some form.

The problem I'm trying to fix is that I'm creating a tools library that is delivered to QA in binary form and used in different projects (made of automatically generated code, FWIW). The QA engineers then need to be able to do source stepping inside the library method calls.

A related problem is, the QA engineer can't use `"Go to definition"` on a library method in the VS editor while **not** debugging.

For problem #1, the QA engineer currently needs to get the appropriate sources from the `SVN` server and manually specify their location to the debugger.

From what I can tell, in Visual Studio (and other debuggers) the traditional way is to [use a `symbol server`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which would provide both the `pdbs` and the sources, having only the library `dll` as input.

I know about [SymbolSource.org](http://www.symbolsource.org/) - it uses 'NuGet symbol packages' (which I currently generate) but management won't agree to host off-site. I had a feeble attempt to set up their free source server offering locally, without much success.

So... is there an easier way (a la Eclipse)?

Comment: You are describing a debugging feature in Eclipse.  Sure, VS has that too.  It isn't clear why you expect this to work without a debugger.  You can, give him the entire solution.